# Burninate [chr] and [ord]?

Tags: feature-request, burninate-request

A quick look at [chr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chr) suggests that often (Python, PHP) it's a function that returns a character, but sometimes it's the character type (R) and sometimes it's a constraint language (Prolog, Haskell). It's not in common use (48 questions over 6 years) and apart from one or two of the VB questions most of the answers don't seem to rely on `chr`-specific expertise. Thoughts?

---

**ETA:** Comments from [Bakuriu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270566/burninate-chr?noredirect=1#comment89478_270566) and [Tikhon Jelvis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270566/burninate-chr?noredirect=1#comment89506_270566) point out that the related [ord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ord) is as bad or worse.

Comment: 48 questions; it’s doable.

Comment: Your requests implies to burninate [`[ord]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ord) too...

Comment: @Bakuriu: `[ord]` is particularly useless because it's sometimes used to mean the character function and sometimes to have something to do with ordering (like Haskell's `Ord` class).

Comment: Excellent point; I assumed `[ord]` would be less stupid but [if anything it's worse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ord).

Comment: I would suggest that any tags relating to specific functions are unhelpful. Want to know how to use ord() in PHP? That's what php.net is for!

Comment: Any question aboutn a specific function I would say should just be tagged with the language, the function name would be in the title, tags for functins don't help at all

Comment: I thought this was English Stackexchange and the question was if Burninate was a real word or not. Of course, peasants should be burninated by Trogdor, I don't know about `chr` and `ord`...  http://www.homestarrunner.com/trogdor.html

Comment: @Prof.Falken: Surely Trogdor should burninate any peasant who thinks brackets are adequate protection against Trogdor, like `chr` and `ord` in this question's title?

Comment: @abarnert, indeed a vain and feeble protection for a function, worthy of scorn. Bracket protection should be reserved for languages and equally important words, peasants should know this or be subjected to just burnination. I now understand Trogdors motivations...